# Using Deeplinks and Different Hyperlinks for Different OSes (User Side)

Tags: html, deep-linking

I want a button to send a user to the normal URL in computer and the Deeplink in mobile environments (Andoird and iOS separation would be a nice touch). Is this possible using vanilla HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, with a mix of HTML and JS.

However in this case you'll need to apply logics based on the user agent that your customer comes from. E.g. for Android you could try to deep link via scheme. For desktop, you can try to redirect to a landing page instead.

Having said that, redirection and deep linking coverage of all optional user agent cases is not an easy task. Moreover, in iOS versions > 9 you'll need a click server that can handle Universal Links in order to deep link to the app.

If you are looking for an industry solution for this, you can refer to: https://www.appsflyer.com/product/one-link-deep-linking/